# Wait for Coroutine execution before updating UI

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I'm making an app uisng Jetpack Compose where i have a composable function that loads some data from a FireStore db and then calls another composable function with the results.

in terms of code, to give an idea, it's something like this:

```
@Composable
fun mainScreen(myData: MutableState<myObject?>)

coroutineScope.launch {
        // loadData() updates a component of mydata, mydata.list which contains a List<String> 
        viewModel.loadData()
                    }
    // load second screen with updated data
    secondScreen(myData)
}
```

Actually secondScreen() gets launched BEFORE coroutine ends because obviously coroutines execute async tasks.

What can i do to call secondScreen AFTER coroutine ends?

Thank you!

Comment: you can call it when you observe your data.

Comment: @EnesZor can you explain it better? Thank you

Comment: We need more code to help you. What happens in `viewModel.loadData()` and in `secondScreen(myData)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of major problems with this.

The first is that you will launch that coroutine and call `loadData` every time this screen recomposes.

Instead you probably want to put this logic in a call to `LaunchEffect`.

Second is you probably don't want to pass the state into `secondScreen` but instead the values.

This is assuming the viewModel holds the state.

```kotlin
@Composable MainScreen() {
   // replace 0 with something that indicates when the data should be loaded again, that this screen could observer through a state.
   LaunchEffect(0) {
      viewModel.loadData()
   }

   val data = viewModel.state.value
   if (data != null) {
       SecondScreen(data)
   }
}
```

Comment: Well,  the fact that the code gets called at every recomposition is intended, since MainScreen is used in different context with different loaded data. I was wandering, what if secondScreen gets reached before loadData() finishes?

Comment: LoadData()  is a suspend function actually

Comment: You still probably don't want to call loadData on every recomposition.  The key argument to LaunchEffect can be used to handle different contexts and data.  With loadData being suspended, is it returning something that should be used to populate the state?  If so populate the state and wait for the data to be there before calling SecondScreen.   If you just have to wait, then remember a new boolean state in MainScreen (use same key as LaunchEffect) and updated when loadData returns.